# Angular 7 does not launch prompts when enter "ng new myProject"

Tags: angular-cli, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu. I have installed: node, npm, webpack, cli, typescript.

When I enter `ng new myProject` in the chosen directory, I do not get questions (or prompts) but some weird kind of console editor.

What should I do to get Angular7 project initialized successfully?

[image]

Comment: Ho did you install Angular "npm install --save -g angular/cli@latest" ?

Comment: Did I have to? What is it for?

Comment: @AnnaKogan Yes, you need to install `angular/cli` as mentioned by above comment. The `ng` commands are from `angular/cli`.

Comment: @SaddamPojee cli is installed but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed `mg new myProject` instead of `ng new myProject`.

`mg` Documentation: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mg.1.html

### UPDATE:

It seems that `ng` has been wrongly mapped. Running the below command, will solve the issue:

```
sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
```

Then install `angular-cli`:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Nope. I checked multiple times - "ng new myProj" I don`t know where 'Mg' came from.

Comment: @AnnaKogan In your screenshot there is a console opened with `mg` command. That's why I posted this answer.

Comment: this editor - like - console  page opens right after I enter "ng new projectname"

Comment: @AnnaKogan maybe `ng` has been mapped to `mg`. Run this command, `sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin` then run `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`